# Any JavaScript/jQuery-based html-data processor/beautifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom

I need to process "dirty" html data on server-side. As I'm using Node.JS **and jQuery on server-side**, I'm able to use all power of JS and jQuery DOM-parser for processing my html content.

"Dirty" data means following:

```
<br ><br />Home <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/post/169139/"> gamy code </ a> 
<br>
Technique: <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/post/173903/"> Preparation methods </ a> <br>
<br>
In continuation, the technique based on the book Refactoring Refactoring <a href="http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/">. Improvement of existing code by Martin Fowler. </ A> <br>
  <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/post/174779/#habracut"> Read more → </ a>
```

So, it may have several br's in the beginning/in the middle, empty p's, etc. I've tried to use

```
$('*:empty').remove();
```

However, if post begins form

```
Home <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/post/169139/"> gamy code </ a> <br>
```

everything before "< a href="http://habrahabr..." is deleted.

**So, are there any reliable production-ready JS/jQuery-based solutions to beautify html data to remove empty tags in the beginning/double br's/p's in the middle, etc?**

p.s. don't want to use simple regexp's 'cause there are so many different cases that may happen in such a dirty content

Comment: You'll need to be even more specific. Beautify usually means nice and tidy, with linebreaks, tabs etc. but the browser does'nt care about that at all, and it's just nonsense if you just plan on inserting the HTML into the DOM. OR, are you trying to remove `<br>` tags and empty `<p>`'s, and if so why, and what else are you trying to remove. You'll have to have a pretty specific target to get a good result.

Comment: @adeneo Certainly, you're right. I need to remove extra/dobule br's and empty p's, make content readable, not just reformat HTML code :)

Comment: And what is an open `<p>` tag. You can have multiple opening `<p>` tags to separate paragraphs, with only one closing `</p>`, so that's not an error, and will be almost impossible to remove with DOM parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin called jQuery-Clean that might be helpful in this scenario: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/

This plugin performs the following operations:

- fix self closing tags
- lower-case tags
- remove non-standard attributes
- remove in-line style attributes
- remove in-line event attributes
- optionally remove other attributes
- tidy unnecessary white space and new lines
- remove comments
- remove proprietary word formatting tags
- replace tags e.g. i=>em
- optionally leave css classes in place
- format and indent html

Unfortunately I was unable to locate anything else. I feel I must say that it might be necessary to write some regular expressions to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, looks fine for me. Dont get me wrong, I'm not a fan of regexp's in such cases. <br>, < br>, <br />, <  P>  < br /><     /p>, etc. It will be quite hard to describe all the variants. I'm working with RSS (RIP Google Reader :)), so data may be really various. That's why I prefer DOM-parsers.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be pretty tough to come up with a solution that works in every scenario for the issues you're encountering. If you come up with something it'd be great if you could come back and share!

Answer (score 0):

Totally, here's one called [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify).  This will beautify Javascript, HTML, CSS, and JSON.

Comment: I don't need to process/reformat JS-code. I need to beautify data/content. Please, read the post.

Comment: Please read my post as well.  This does more than just Javascript code, read the documentation at the link I sent you... towards the bottom.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe there's some kind of misunderstanding. May this tool be helpful in removing empty tags? I've tried my code (from the post) on http://jsbeautifier.org/ and except formatting, couldn't find any difference. Please, correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's a tool that's just meant to format HTML, Javascript, JSON, and CSS.  But it seems you found a better answer, glad you got the response you needed!